# Is it possible to use css to style a div to appear over the full screen map from the Google Maps API?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making a web app using AngularJS, HTML, CSS, and JQuery. This app uses the google maps api, and I need to have the highlighted div below appear on top of the map when it goes fullscreen.

[image: a website with a div highlighted]

All solutions to this problem that I've found were meant for when the map goes fullscreen within the browser, but in my case I need it to work for when the map goes legitimately full screen to the edges of the screen. No matter how much z-index I give the .fixed class, the div will not appear over the google map fullscreen. HTML, JS, and CSS below:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="airQualityCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <!-- Everything for the air quality page -->
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch" id="input-row">
        <div class="col-7 padding-sm">
            <div class="ui-card" id="input-card">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h2 class="title text-lg">Choose Location</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content padding-top-md">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h3 class="bold text-md no-margin">Location</h3>
                        <input ng-model="location" ng-keyup="submitLocation($event);" class="form-control" type="text" name="location"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h3 class="bold text-md no-margin">Latitude / Longitude</h3>
                        <input ng-model="location" ng-keyup="submitLocation($event);" class="form-control" type="text" name="location"/>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 padding-sm">
            <div class="ui-card">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h2 class="title text-lg">Choose Date</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div id="date-picker">
                        <div class="month d-flex justify-content-between">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left transitions"></i>
                            <h3 class="bold text-md no-margin text-center">March</h3>
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right transitions unavailable"></i>
                        </div>
                        <table>
                            <tr id="week1">
                                <td class="gray-date">25</td>
                                <td class="gray-date">26</td>
                                <td class="gray-date">27</td>
                                <td class="gray-date">28</td>
                                <td>01</td>
                                <td>02</td>
                                <td>03</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="week2">
                                <td>04</td>
                                <td>05</td>
                                <td>06</td>
                                <td>07</td>
                                <td>08</td>
                                <td>09</td>
                                <td>10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="week3">
                                <td>11</td>
                                <td>12</td>
                                <td>13</td>
                                <td>14</td>
                                <td>15</td>
                                <td>16</td>
                                <td>17</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="week4">
                                <td class="selected">18</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">19</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">20</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">21</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">22</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">23</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">24</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="week5">
                                <td class="unavailable">25</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">26</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">27</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">28</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">29</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">30</td>
                                <td class="unavailable">31</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="col-7 padding-sm">
            <div class="ui-card map">
                <div id="map" class="full-size"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 padding-sm">
            <div class="ui-card">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <h2 class="title text-lg">Results</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="data">
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                        <p>Data line 1: CO2 - 30% | O2 - 50% | NaCl - 20%</p>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="bold text-md no-margin">Filter</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.mapInit = function() {
    //creates a map centered at Minneapolis
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: 44.9778, lng: -93.2650}
    });

    $scope.map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {

        var mapElement = $('#map div');
        if(mapElement.height() >= window.innerHeight && mapElement.width() >= window.innerWidth && !$scope.isFullScreen) {

            //  if the map element is fullscreen but isFullscreen has not been flagged, make the fullscreen css changes
            $scope.isFullscreen = true;
            $('#input-card').addClass('fixed');

        }

    });

    $scope.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
};
```

CSS

```
/*  COLORS

    DARK GREEN     #77997e
    GREEN          #d9f4c7
    BLUE           #a1edd5
    GRAY           #a8a8a8
    LIGHT GRAY     #f9f9f9

*/

body {
    background: #d9f4c7;
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

i:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #a1edd5;
}

.transitions {
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

/* CARD CSS */
.ui-card {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    height: 100%;
}

.card-title {
    background: #77997e;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.card-content {
    padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;

    z-index: 1000;
}

.form-control {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a8a8a8;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    width: 80%;
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a1edd5;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #77997e;
}

.btn-custom {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: #d9f4c7;
}

.data {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #a8a8a8;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}


/* DATE CSS */
.month {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.map {
    height: 500px;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

td:hover {
    color: #a1edd5;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.gray-date {
    color: #a8a8a8;
}

.selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a1edd5;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.unavailable {
    color: white;
}

.unavailable:hover {
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
}

.full-size{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a demo URL for this app? Or can you create a **working** snippet / fiddle / bin for it? BTW, you don't need to create the snippet with all your code (angular etc), just simulate the situation..

Comment: It's a rather large project that uses multiple html files being lumped together with AngularJS. I'm not too sure how I would begin to go about moving it onto something like codepen.

Comment: Have you tried adding an on.("click", event to the button that makes it go fullscreen? You could on click add display:none to the div that has the map in it?

Comment: A very basic JSFiddle here shows what I mean - https://jsfiddle.net/Rockhopper92/e8602jyv/

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/4806/
Works fine also with fixed position.

Comment: @SamuelCole Like I said, you can create a snippet with the specific scenario, for example, map with the `div` which you want to display above it. Otherwise, it's pretty hard to help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't provide any event for detecting full screen mode, but you can use a [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) for this purpose. The idea is to listen the `fullscreenchange` event on your document. Once you go to full screen mode move the div you are interested in into custom map controls array, so it appears on top of the map, once you leave the full screen mode move the div to its original position.

Have a look at my sample that demonstrates this approach

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });

    $(document).bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function() {
      var isFullScreen = document.fullScreen ||
        document.mozFullScreen ||
        document.webkitIsFullScreen;
      if (isFullScreen) {
        console.log('fullscreen mode!');
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($("#content").get(0));
      } else {
        console.log('not fullscreen mode!');
        var elem = map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].pop();
        $(elem).removeAttr("style").prependTo("body");
      }
    });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}
#content {
  height: 90px;
  width: 150px;  
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed #f69c55;
  background-color:yellow;
}
#map #content {
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  My content div
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

You can also see this example on jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/arumdt4r/

I hope this helps!